# Python Regex for Securities

Tags: python, regex, finance

I have a text file that contains security name, $ amounts, and % of the portfolio. I'm trying to figure out how to separate the companies using regex. I had an original solution that allowed me to `.split('%')` and then create the 3 variables I needed, but I discovered some of the securities contain `%` in their name and thus the solution was inadequate.

**String example:**

```
Pinterest, Inc. Series F, 8.00%$24,808,9320.022%ResMed,Inc.$23,495,3260.021%Eaton Corp. PLC$53,087,8430.047%
```

**Current regex**

```
[a-zA-Z0-9,$.\s]+[.0-9%]$
```

My current regex only finds the last company. example, `Eaton Corp. PLC$53,087,8430.047%`

Any help on how I can find every single instance of a company?

**Solution desired**

```
["Pinterest, Inc. Series F, 8.00%$24,808,9320.022%","ResMed,Inc.$23,495,3260.021%","Eaton Corp. PLC$53,087,8430.047%"]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python 3:

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'[^$]+\$[^%]+%')
p.findall('Pinterest, Inc. Series F, 8.00%$24,808,9320.022%ResMed,Inc.$23,495,3260.021%Eaton Corp. PLC$53,087,8430.047%')
```

Result:

```
['Pinterest, Inc. Series F, 8.00%$24,808,9320.022%', 'ResMed,Inc.$23,495,3260.021%', 'Eaton Corp. PLC$53,087,8430.047%']
```

Your initial issue was that the `$` anchor made the regex only match at the end of the line.  However, removing the `$` still split Pinterest into two entries at the `%` after `8.00`.

To fix that, the regex looks for a `$`, then a `%` after that, and takes everything up through the `%` as an entry.  That pattern works for the examples you gave, but, of course, I can't know if it holds true for all your data.

**Edit** The regex works like this:

```
r'               Use a raw string so you don't have to double the backslashes
  [^$]+          Look for anything up to the next $
       \$        Match the $ itself (\$ because $ alone means end-of-line)
         [^%]+   Now anything up to the next %
              %  And the % itself
               ' End of the string
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

A working solution for Python, with named groups: https://regex101.com/r/sqkFaN/2

```
(?P<item>(?P<name>.*?)\$(?P<usd>[\d,\.]*?%))
```

At the link I provided you can see changes have effect in real-time, and the sidebar provides an explanation for the used syntax.

Comment: It does grab what I wanted. The group for USD does include a % sign in addition to a decimal to the thousandth .XXX though.